# having a problem finding object in my data even though its in there and creating a scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, scatter-plot

```
dat <- read.csv(file.choose("MH_Prolific_June"))

ggscatter(dat, x="mh", y="Empathy", add="reg.line", conf.int = TRUE, cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson", xlab= "Moral Humility", ylab = "Empathy")
```

Here's what I have and here's the error code:

```
Error in (function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "smooth", position = "identity", :

ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! object 'mh' not found
```

Not sure why i cant find the object when its in the data

Comment: Can you please run `dput(head(dat))` and copy the output into the body of your question?

Comment: Try passing ```mh``` and ```Empathy``` as objects rather than strings. That is, remove the ```""```. Not sure if that will work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Note to Shubaranjan:  Please make sure to list **all** loaded libraries that are used in your code sample.  I'm guessing you are using `ggpubr` ?

Comment: @scott.pilgrim.vs.r  `x` and `y` are supposed to be the names of items in the input data (i.e  `dataframe$x`  and so on).  So until we see what the OP's "dat" object looks like, we can't say for sure.